# Problems with the input of a linear regression function in python (Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').)

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, input, model-fitting

I'm trying to analyze a dataset and I need to feed it to a linear regression function.
When I try to do that this error comes out:

> Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for
> dtype('float64').

I've searched for NaN values doing:

```
dataset.isnull().sum()
```

And also

```
dataset.isna().sum()
```

Since some values in a feature in the dataset were NaN, i've provided to delete those elements with:

```
dataset=dataset.dropna(axis=0, how='any', thresh=None, subset=['Flow Bytes/s'], inplace=False)
```

It worked, but didn't resolve the problem.
I've tried so to convert every possible infinity value to NaN with:

```
dataset.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
```

and then again I removed the NaN elements.

Even so, trying to use the linear regression i still obtain the same error. Do you have any idea why?